# Issue with maven pom.xml build after Assembla set up integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, assembla

My project was working fine in my local system . When I integrated my set up with ASSEMBLA folder structure got little change. Now I am unable to build my project . POM.xml has encountered some problem .

I am using 
1.Eclipse Luna
2.spring,hibernate
3.Maven 2

Is it because I shared my project with Assemble through svn ?? Any one has faced such issue earlier ..?
Please do give some suggestions

Comment: Without your pom file and a more detailed described what you have tried what does not work it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: now its fine .... there some issue the new eclipse luna ,,,